# Sending email-Iphone simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I've create an application where the user is able to send some info to others via email. But how could i test this on simulator? Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not possible to send emails from the Simulator. You need to test this on a real device (iPhone/iPod touch).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot send mails through Simulator. Instead you can install the application in device and try from there.

Simulator just displays the composer but wont allow you to send mails. Sent Successfully is just the acknowledgment that your code is fine and there is no issue that terminates it while sending.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to send emails using simulator.

You need a real device to check it.

the notitification of message sent is just to tell user that the code is proper.